# Expression.Bind() - what does it actually do?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression, expression-trees

So I've been playing with dynamically building expression trees lately and came across this method, which seems kinda odd. At first I thought "oh cool this is exactly what I need" after constantly writing code along the lines of

```
var left = member is FieldInfo ? Expression.Field(instance, (FieldInfo)member) : Expression.Property(instance, (PropertyInfo)member);
var right = ...
var assign = Expression.Assign(left, right);
```

Yes, I know there is `Expression.PropertyOrField()` call, but it does roundtrip back to reflection to find member by name, where as I typically already have `MemberInfo` instance.

So anyway, I thought `Expression.Bind()` would be useful to me, but it does something I don't really understand. Given the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    var m = typeof(Foo).GetField("Bar");
    Expression.Bind(m, Expression.Constant("")).Dump();
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
}
```

it produces `MemberAssignment` expression `Bar = ""`. But there is no instance and no static reference. How would I ever apply this expression to and instance of `Foo`? I can't find any example of this method being used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Object-Initializer expressions**.

Let's say you had:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Property { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var newExpr = Expression.New(typeof(Foo));
var bindExprs = new[]
    {
        Expression.Bind(typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Property"), parameter)
        // You can bind more properties here if you like.
    };

var body = Expression.MemberInit(newExpr, bindExprs);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, Foo>>(body, parameter);
```

which is something like:

```
i => new Foo { Property = i }
```

## Old:

<s>I can't help you solve the "performance issue" you are determined to solve (will using Expression.PropertyOrField really introduce a bottleneck in your application? I'm somewhat skeptical. You should determine this before optimizing prematurely)</s> (**EDIT**: Apologies for incorrectly assuming that this was a perf optimization, and as you've found out yourself, Expression.MakeMemberAccess is what you need), but I *can* tell you what `Expression.Bind` is useful for.

Comment: oooh... I thought that is what it is, but I was expecting an overload of `Expression.New()` to accept that. It didn't occur to me that could be a totally different call.

Comment: Regarding not using `PropertyOrField`: that is not really optimization. More like for my own sanity.

Comment: Ah, if that's the case, then why not write a little helper that takes a `MemberInfo` and branches as appropriate?

Comment: I have... it just seems like a very common operation that should have a standard implementation.

Comment: Fair enough; apologies for jumping to conclusions!

Comment: Incidentally... apparently there is this thing `Expression.MakeMemberAccess`, which does exactly what I need... *hangs head in shame*